# React (Native): Set state to false just on 1st-time loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to validate email by regex, it works fine except that during the 1st time loading of the page, I don't want to display the 'wrong email format' icon.

```
const [emailIcon, setEmailIcon] = React.useState(false)

function ValidateEmail () {
    const regexIsValid = regexEmail.test(username) 
    if(regexIsValid) {
            setEmailIcon(false)
        } else {
            setEmailIcon(true)
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        ValidateEmail()
    })
```

The moment the page renders, `useEffect` runs `ValidateEmail()`, therefore setting `emailIcon` to `true` because blank doesn't meet the regex.

Should I be using `useEffect` for this anyway?

Comment: Have you decided when you want it to validate?  Not on first load, ok, do you want to validate when there's data in the input, or the user hits a submit button?  If it's the first one, use onChangeText or onChange for the input, if it's the second, rig it up to onPress for the button

Comment: Thank you, I ran `ValidateEmail()` through `onChangeText` and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ran `ValidateEmail()` through the `<TextInput>`'s `onChangeText` and it works as I intended now:

```
const ValidateEmail = (text) => {
        const regexIsValid = regexEmail.test(username) 
        if(regexIsValid) {
            setEmailIcon(false)
            setUsername(text)
        } else {
            setEmailIcon(true)
            setUsername(text)
        }
    }
```

The `<Textinput>`

```
<TextInput 
    placeholder="username"
    value = {username}
    onChangeText={text=>ValidateEmail(text)} />
```

So no more `useEffect`